Cannot download pdf after upgrading JasperReport Library
I am currently upgrading the JasperReports Library from version 6.0.4 to 7.0.0. My system is currently using the following JasperReports libraries:

jasperreports-fonts-6.0.4.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-6.0.4.jar

After upgrading these libraries, along with their dependencies and other JasperReports libraries:

jasperreports-7.0.0.jar
jasperreports-jdt-7.0.0.jar

The system throws an error when attempting to download the report (PDF). My system using Java Servlet.
System Error:
ERROR http-nio-8080-exec-3 OCSASTDFP :: [O00045.java:281] :: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to load report
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:172)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:136)
    ...

Tomcat Error:
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler - Exception occurred during processing request: Cannot invoke "java.io.PrintWriter.print(String)" because "this.pw" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.PrintWriter.print(String)" because "this.pw" is null
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethodInsideSandbox(OgnlRuntime.java:1245) ~[ognl-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1230) ~[ognl-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1958) ~[ognl-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68) ~[ognl-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98) ~[struts2-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90) ~[struts2-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]

I've tried following some suggestions from StackOverflow and the Jasper Community, including adding:

jasperreports-7.0.0.jar
jasperreports-jdt-7.0.0.jar

However, this issue still persists.

your error message: because "this.pw" is null , what is pw ?

@life888888 it actually to send text output to the client in a servlet or other Java-based web application.
eg code:
import java.io.PrintWriter; public PrintWriter pw = null; pw = response.getWriter();

I have added the necessary *.jar files from JasperReports 7. The PDF downloads, but it cannot be viewed.




The PDF downloads, but it cannot be viewed.<<< , you are in linux or windows ? PDF file size ? 0 or other ? if you are in linux , try command file xxx.pdf , can check file, or use cat xxx.pdf | more , maybe the pdf file is wrong. (maybe it is a Html Error Messages , not pdf content)




Using windows, PDF file size is 0

The PDF file size is 0, which is a failure, not a success. (Failed to render PDF? Or failed to download PDF?, I guess, failed to render PDF)

Please check your server log files.

i throw this error:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FopGlyphProcessor
I tried adding itextpdf-5.5.13.4.jar, but the same issue occurred.

(1) please remove all jasperreports-xxx-6.0.4.jar from your project , if you want to use jasperreports 7.0.0, (2) I download the jasperreports 6 source code, found pom.xml use com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7 , (3) jasperreports 7.0.0 , pom.xml use com.github.librepdf:openpdf:1.3.30.jaspersoft.2, it is use openpdf , not itext. (4) add jasperreports-pdf-7.0.0.jar ,

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FopGlyphProcessor, This error message means that your project is still using the 6 package, not the 7.0.0 package. (please remove all jasperreports-xxx-6.0.4.jar from your project)

Thank you so much! You've been incredibly helpful. I changed from iText to OpenPDF, and now the PDF can be viewed.

@life888888 I got issue when want to download XLS format, now there is no issue when download PDF and XLSX. error occurred - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter
Do you have any idea about this?

add <dependency>     <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>     <artifactId>jasperreports-excel-poi</artifactId>     <version>7.0.0</version> </dependency> , because JRXlsExporter in jasperreports 6.x , but not existing in jasperreports 7, it move to jasperreports-excel-poi 7

How to find it all ? (1) google maven JRXlsExporter , find first result Maven Repository(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports) (2) open link 7.0.0 , find Files pom (8 KB)  jar (3.5 MB)  View All, download jar (3) unzip jasperreports-7.0.0.jar , use file exploere to search JRXlsExporter , find nothing. (4) open link 6.21.2 , download jar file (5) unzip jasperreports-6.21.2.jar (6) use file exploere to search JRXlsExporter , find JRXlsExporter. (7) This means that JRXlsExporter exists in jasperreports-6 but not in jasperreports-7.

(8) google find JasperReports - Configuration Reference(https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=zh-TW&_x_tr_pto=wapp) , you can search JRXlsExporter in this page, it existed.
(9) This means that JRXlsExporter still exists in jasperreports 7, but it is definitely not the jasperreports 7 package name.

(10)  Open https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports again and look to see if it may be related to xls (excel ,  poi). We found a package name jasperreports-excel-poi, it is possible Yes.
(11) We open the link, JasperReports Excel POI 7.0.0, download the jar file.
(12) Unzip jasperreports-excel-poi-7.0.0.jar, search for JRXlsExporter, it exists.
(13) So in jasperreports 7.0, you have to add JasperReports Excel POI 7.0.0.
This is the whole process of finding the answer.

Thanks for your very much for your excellent explanation, i have added jasperreports-excel-poi-7.0.0.jar, jasperreports-fastexcel-7.0.0.jar and upgrade poi-*.jar version but same error still occur.

Before going any further, have you read the following paragraph?  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%207.0.0/ , - breaking backward compatibility of serialized/compiled *.jasper report template files,  mostly because of historical deprecated serialization code removal/cleanup mentioned above  (source *.jrxml report templates need to be recompiled to *.jasper using the new version of  the library); ,

- breaking backward compatibility of source *.jrxml report template files and *.jrtx style  template files by replacing the Apache Commons Digester based parsers with Jackson XML object  serialization. *.jrxml and *.jrtx files created with version 6 or older can no longer be loaded  with version 7 or newer of the library alone. The conversion from the old file formats to the new  file formats and back can be made using Jaspersoft Studio 7 and later versions of it;

based on the paragraph given, what i understand is need to recompile the .jrxml file with new version of library. If yes i already recompile *.jrxml file with JasperStudio 7.

I currently do not have a minimal sample that can be tested, including program files and report files (especially those developed using version 7), so there is no way to conduct further testing.

It was a simple mistake on my part. I checked my program and noticed it was using import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter;. I changed it to import net.sf.jasperreports.poi.export.JRXlsExporter; and added SparseBitSet.
It works now, and I can download .xls files. Thank a lot Jasper Sifu!! @life888888

I encountered the same issue when upgrading to JasperReports 7.0.1. I resolved it by adding the jasperreports-excel-poi dependency to my project.

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-excel-poi</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


